# Include changes to git hook files in a commit

Tags: git, github, version-control, hook

I'm working on a repo and the git hook files(inside the '.git/hook' directory) have and issue. How can I propose changes to these hooks to the repo owners?
The project in hosted on github.

Comment: I think nothing in .git can be tracked.

Comment: As others have said, the contents of `.git/` are per-repository. They are not tracked or shared. I think the question is: how did your local `.git/hook/` directory get populated in the first place?

Comment: For the git hook files, they can only effect for your local git repo. If you do need to manage the git hooks files into git repo, I suggest: **Option 1**, manage them into a separate repo and copy the files into `.git/hooks` folder of the local git repo you want to use. **Option 2**, use relative shortcuts for these files and add the relative shortcuts (a post for relative shortcuts https://superuser.com/questions/644407/using-relative-paths-for-windows-shortcuts) into your git repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you only see an issue, but don't have a fix, [create an issue](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue/) on the GitHub repository.

However if you also know how to fix it, [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the repository and [create a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/).

Answer (score 0):

Stuff in `$WORKDIR/.git` is untrackable. If you want to track it, you need to move it to your working directory

You can then use a relative symlink to make sure git uses the same hooks as the ones you're tracking.

For all git hooks:

```
mv .git/hooks .
ln -s ../hooks .git/
git add hooks
```

For just one (pre-commit, in this case):

```
mv .git/hooks/pre-commit . 
ln -s ../../pre-commit .git/hooks/
git add pre-commit
```